# Are there any benefits of (Hibernate) load() vs get() with field access and bytecode enhancement?

Tags: hibernate

TL;DR 
load() results in a proxy object even though we use bytecode enhancement with field access. Why? What is the benefit? Can we get load() laziness without the proxy? This is unexpected and also causes some test failures for us.

Context (skip if in rush):

We are updating a large legacy application from older version of Hibernate to 5.4. For numerous future looking reasons we opted to go with field access (used to be property) and build time bytecode enhancement (all fields are private and all entity classes are contained in a single project out of many).

The old application devs tried hard to make some things lazy load (for good or bad reasons) but they didn't succeed as they missed quite a few things, including declaring many properties as eagerly loaded in original hbm.xml files (we are moving that to annotations, all lazy and will use entity graphs to specify what to load eagerly per use case).

We've gotten to a point where only a few of tens of thousands of tests are failing with the updated code. Some fail because our entity "name" (property) duplication constraints are violated (as apparent to the API client, not DB) and one thing we tracked this to is the use of the load() vs. get() method to obtain some entities.

Now, I am not looking for help in finding the actual defect here but eliminating my confusion and (somewhat) a surprise that load() returns a proxy object even though the main class has been "bytecode enhanced" at build time. I thought this isn't necessary any more (with bytecode enhancement) and they even load() will return the instance if the same/main class, only perhaps "less initialized".

In any case, if I change load() to get() the tests pass and I am considering just replacing them all with get() but am worried about other benefits that I may be missing beyond the possible small SQL select (as all properties are mapped as last). Can anyone help me understand the reasons and benefits of load() in bytecode enhancement case?